# Issue when Updating list of entities at once - OpenJpa

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, openjpa

I am using OpenJPA as a JPA provider and try to update list of Entities at once. But I am gettong bellow error.

```
Exception in thread "P=866223:O=0:CT" <openjpa-2.0.0-r422266:935683 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: No metadata was found for type "class java.util.ArrayList". The class is not enhanced.
```

We added the annotation for the List which we use as bellow.

```
@ElementCollection
private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

And we added bellow part in persistence.xml

```
<property name="openjpa.MetaDataFactory" value="jpa(Types=java.util.ArrayList)"/>
```

Can anybody please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post snippets of the Entities that you are trying to persist? Also post the contents of your persistence.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following mapping in your configuration file.

```
<property name="openjpa.MetaDataFactory" value="jpa(Types=java.util.List)"/>
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. <br> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: No metadata was found for type "class java.util.ArrayList". The class is not enhanced.